# Building a function from 3 given properties

Tags: functional-equations

Is there a real function $f$ / algebraic expression, such that

- $f(-3) = 1$
- $f(3) = 1$
- $f(x) = - f(x)$ for all $-3 < x < 3$

I was able to construct some $f$ with Fourier analysis and complex arguments but this wasn't what I was looking for. :(

Comment: something is missing -- why not take $f(x) = 0$ when $|x| \ne 3$ and $f(-3) = f(3) = 1$? Did you mean a continuous function perhaps? That'd likely be hard since $f(3) \ne - f(-3)$...

Comment: What does your 'algebraic expression' mean? If dividing cases are possible, @gt6989b 's function is easily possible, too, and there are lots of functions... (Even if it's not possible, $f(x)=[|x/3|]$ is possible, too.)